# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=

Tags: mysqli

I keep getting this error message and I tried a few thing that I found but nothing has worked. here is my subquery;

```
icd9_code =(select icd9_code  from paragon_rpt.dbo.TSM910_ICD9_REF 
         where icd9_int_id = (select Top 2 (icd9_int_id) from paragon_rpt.dbo.TPM317_VISIT_PROCEDURE
                        where vst_int_id =a.vst_int_id
                        and
                        icd9_int_id in (Select icd9_int_id from SGMH_Reports.dbo.NHSN_ICD10_2)
                        )),
```

Comment: Please read your question title. That's the answer to your problem.

Comment: replace `=` with `in` to allow multiple values

Comment: @Lashane I tried that too.. but changing to in gave me the same error       icd9_code = (select icd9_code  from paragon_rpt.dbo.TSM910_ICD9_REF 
         where icd9_int_id in (select Top 2 (icd9_int_id) from paragon_rpt.dbo.TPM317_VISIT_PROCEDURE
            
                        where vst_int_id = a.vst_int_id
                        and
                        icd9_int_id in (Select icd9_int_id from SGMH_Reports.dbo.NHSN_ICD10_2)
                        )),

Comment: you haven't replaced `icd9_code =`

Answer (score 0):

changing the = to in worked after I added a ) after a.vst_in_id.

icd9_code =(select icd9_code  from paragon_rpt.dbo.TSM910_ICD9_REF 
         where icd9_int_id in (select Top 2 (icd9_int_id) from paragon_rpt.dbo.TPM317_VISIT_PROCEDURE
                        where vst_int_id =a.vst_int_id)
                        and
                        icd9_int_id in (Select icd9_int_id from SGMH_Reports.dbo.NHSN_ICD10_2)),

Thanks so much for your help!